# xaxis numbers not printed on log-scale plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The numbers on the x-axis disappear when turning on "log" scale.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot( range(1,10) , range(1,10) ,  color='#aaaaff')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xticks(range(1,10) )
plt.show()
```

If I comment out `xscale` the numbers on the x-axis are printed. Can someone shed light on why this does not work on `log` scale axis and how this can be achieved?

Edit:

Simplified code, so that it can be used without the data file. Same thing: No numbers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default tick locations for log axes are in base 10. So in the above case the only possible `xtick` is at 1.

If you change the `xticks` to

```
plt.xticks([1,10])
```

you get ticks at `1` and `10`.

You can also play with `ticker` which allows you to do many stuff. E.g.,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

fig = plt.figure(1, [5,4])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot( range(1,100) , range(1,100) ,  color='#aaaaff')
ax.set_xscale('log')
# This is default, so play with it
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(base = 10.0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you use:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(base = 100.0))
```

then you get

[image]

Comment: Ok, great! Now, how can I set the ticks (and numbers) to 2,4,8,16 ? I am asking because `ax.xaxis` has no `xticks` !

Comment: Use `ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)`.